# WPF window inserting an array into DataGrid

Tags: wpf

WPF window in C# doesn't have option of Inserting something into DataGrid immediately, like as WinForms Form

```
DataGridView.Rows.Add(whatever)
```

What is alternative for this code ?
So how can I insert an array into DataGridView in WPF window?

Comment: Create an List. For eg: `List<Datatype> mylist = new List<Datatype>` 

Add some data to your List: `mylist.Add(blah)`

Bind this to your datagrid in C#: `datagrid.ItemsSource = mylist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually add objects directly to the `Items` property of the `DataGrid`:

```
dataGrid.Items.Add(whatever);
```

But if you want to be able to edit the items, you should set or bind the `ItemsSource` property to an `IList`:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<object> { whatever };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection.  If you insert into the ObservableCollection, it'll appear on the UI